# add more id in a report from the same table

Tags: python, html, odoo

I am making a report which can print all the accounts created in a table in one. For example: I have the account created "Cash", "Bank" and "Payable" so I select all three and they appear in a report. I currently do it but it only appears when I select 1 it does not work with several.

The error shown when making this report is as follows:

**Error to render compiling AST
ValueError: Expected singleton: proyecto_rc.account(3, 4)
Template: 249
Path: /templates/t/t/t/t/div/div/thead/br/p/table/tbody/td[2]/span
Node:  - - -**

Here I leave a picture of how I want it to be.: [photo example](https://ibb.co/S0YJ0GW)

```
<report
    id="list_efectcredit"
    model="proyecto_rc.account"
    string="Lmayor"
    name="proyecto_rc.report_account_view"
    file="proyecto_rc.report_lmayorefectivo"
    report_type="qweb-html" />


<template id="report_account_view">
    <t t-call="web.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
            <t t-call="web.external_layout">
                <div class="page">
                    <div class="page">
                        <br></br>

                        <thead>
                            <center>
                                <h2>Ledger</h2>
                            </center>
                            <br>
                                <p>Detail:
                                    <table class="customTable">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Account</th>
                                                <th>Debit</th>
                                                <th>Credit</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <t t-set="i" t-value="1"/>

                                                <td>
                                                    <span t-field="o.title"/>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <span t-field="o.total_account_debit"/>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <span t-field="o.total_account_credit"/>
                                                </td>
                                            <t t-set="i" t-value="i+1"/>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </p>   
                            </br>

                        </thead>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </t>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example

```
   <template id="report_account_view_detail">                 
    <table class="customTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Account</th>
                <th>Debit</th>
                <th>Credit</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <t t-set="i" t-value="1"/>

                <td>
                    <span t-field="account.title"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span t-field="account.total_account_debit"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span t-field="account.total_account_credit"/>
                </td>
            <t t-set="i" t-value="i+1"/>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>

 <template id="report_account_view">
    <t t-call="web.html_container">
        <t t-call="web.external_layout">
            <div class="page">
                <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="account">
                    <t t-call="proyecto_rc.report_account_view_detail">
                        <t t-set="account" t-value="account"/>
                    </t>
                </t>
            </div>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
```